# Loader Event Complete function only being called once

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, loader

So, I'm trying to load resources, add them to a dictionary, and have a drawing method search through that dictionary and draw based on certain predicates. I have a function that iterates through an `Vector` of `String`s, calling on an instance of `Loader` to load them instantiated as a `URLRequest`.

```
    private function loadImages(urls:Vector.<String>):void
    {
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();

        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,ioErrorHandler);

        var loadResource:Function = function(item:String,index:int,vector:Vector.<String>):void
        {
                loader.load(new URLRequest(item));
        }

        urls.forEach(loadResource);
    }
```

I then have an event handler that's handling the load completion, calling a drawing method that finds the Loaded bitmap in a `Dictionary`.

```
    public function completeHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        var loader:Loader = Loader(event.target.loader);
        var bm:BitmapData = new BitmapData(loader.width,loader.height,false);
        bm.draw(loader,new Matrix());
        this.bmDict[loader.contentLoaderInfo.url] = bm;
        trace("complete handler" + loader.contentLoaderInfo.url);
        trace(this.bmDict[loader.contentLoaderInfo.url]);
        this.drawSprite(loader.contentLoaderInfo.url);
    }
```

My drawsprite function
public function drawSprite(resourceUrl:String):void
            {
            var drawFunct:Function = function(spr:Dictionary,index:int,vector:Vector.):void
            {

```
            var sprRen:SpriteRenderer = new SpriteRenderer();

            trace(resourceUrl.search("blue"));
            trace(resourceUrl.search("drkOrange"));
            trace(resourceUrl.search("green"));
            trace(resourceUrl.search("ltblue"));
            trace(resourceUrl.search("orange"));
            trace(resourceUrl.search("pink"));
            trace(resourceUrl.search("purple"));
            trace(resourceUrl.search("red"));
            trace(resourceUrl.search("yellow"));
            trace(spr.color);

        if((resourceUrl.search("blue") != -1) && (spr["color"] == 1)) {
            var bigBm:BitmapData = sprRen.renderType(spr["type"],bmDict[resourceUrl]);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.beginBitmapFill(bigBm,null,true,false);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.drawRect(0,0,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.endFill();
        } else if ((resourceUrl.search("drkOrange") != -1) && (spr["color"] == 2)){
            var bigBm:BitmapData = sprRen.renderType(spr["type"],bmDict[resourceUrl]);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.beginBitmapFill(bigBm,null,true,false);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.drawRect(0,0,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.endFill();

        } else if ((resourceUrl.search("green") != -1) && (spr["color"] == 3)){
            var bigBm:BitmapData = sprRen.renderType(spr["type"],bmDict[resourceUrl]);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.beginBitmapFill(bigBm,null,true,false);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.drawRect(0,0,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.endFill();

        } else if ((resourceUrl.search("ltblue") != -1) && (spr["color"] == 4)){
            var bigBm:BitmapData = sprRen.renderType(spr["type"],bmDict[resourceUrl]);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.beginBitmapFill(bigBm,null,true,false);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.drawRect(0,0,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.endFill();

        } else if ((resourceUrl.search("orange") != -1) && (spr["color"] == 5)){
            var bigBm:BitmapData = sprRen.renderType(spr["type"],bmDict[resourceUrl]);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.beginBitmapFill(bigBm,null,true,false);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.drawRect(0,0,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.endFill();

        } else if ((resourceUrl.search("pink") != -1) && (spr["color"] == 6)){
            var bigBm:BitmapData = sprRen.renderType(spr["type"],bmDict[resourceUrl]);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.beginBitmapFill(bigBm,null,true,false);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.drawRect(0,0,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.endFill();

        } else if ((resourceUrl.search("purple") != -1) && (spr["color"] == 7)){
            var bigBm:BitmapData = sprRen.renderType(spr["type"],bmDict[resourceUrl]);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.beginBitmapFill(bigBm,null,true,false);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.drawRect(0,0,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.endFill();

        } else if ((resourceUrl.search("red") != -1) && (spr["color"] == 8)){
            var bigBm:BitmapData = sprRen.renderType(spr["type"],bmDict[resourceUrl]);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.beginBitmapFill(bigBm,null,true,false);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.drawRect(0,0,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.endFill();

        } else if ((resourceUrl.search("yellow") != -1) && (spr["color"] == 9)){
            var bigBm:BitmapData = sprRen.renderType(spr["type"],bmDict[resourceUrl]);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.beginBitmapFill(bigBm,null,true,false);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.drawRect(0,0,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE,BIG_SPRITE_SCALE);
            spr["sprite"].graphics.endFill();

        }

        }

        sprites.forEach(drawFunct);
        }
```

So the issue is: Only the first images in my `Vector` are drawing. Upon further inspection, I found that the completeHandler was only being called once (I put a trace in the complete handler to check). However, the `Loader` is invoking load everytime the loop iterates. I tried instantiating separate loaders for each resource, just to see if it would work, but I had no luck with that. Do I need to make separate loaders *and* event handlers? Or am I just not using Loader correctly?

Comment: I'm not seeing any code that's adding the `Loader` to the display list.

Comment: I'm just using the loader for the `BitmapData` class' `draw()` method, which draws the loaded resource onto a `BitmapData` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using only one loader to load multiple files in the same time, it can't work, a `Loader` can handle only one file at the same time.
So you need one loader by resource or load resources one by one if you want to use only one loader.

Comment: I tried using multiple loaders, but I was having some issues there too. I might have had some other problem, but I know I _did_ use the same event listener for all of the loader instances. I thought that might've been the problem, but looking back I can't see why it would be. It's just a reference to a function you're passing the event listener. I'll try multiple Loaders again and see if I can get it to work.